# 2010 Macbook pro trackpad working but not working well

Tags: touchpad, macbook-pro

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (which is the latest LTS) on my 2010 MacBook Pro 7,1 and everything works, including the WiFi which I was surprised about. But there is a slight problem with the trackpad, it works, although sometimes mid-swipe or click it stops responding, but as soon as I lift up my finger and do the swipe or click again it works, until it doesn't. And sometimes it doesn't work altogether for a good 3 seconds.
It's not the end of the world but it always means that whenever I'm using the trackpad almost half of my swipes don't work or don't fully work.

Example: I will be swiping my finger and halfway through the mouse stops moving until I try again or sometimes does nothing.

I initially did a system update through Ubuntu Software and a `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but the problem persists.

This happens only in Linux (under both Xorg and Wayland) so I know the trackpad is not broken but no drivers I can find fix it